# C#: Write hight speed data(50M/s) to local disk in real time

Tags: c#, performance, file, real-time

My application has to writing received UDP data to disk continuously, and the speed is about 40M/s - 50M/s. My current logic is that all data is cached in a queue and Create a BinaryWriter to write queue data to local disk. It works well most time, but sometimes the writing speed will be very slow and causes cached data too large, then my application crushes.

Is there any method to improve writing file speed and keep a stable writing speed? Or i have to adjust my hardware?

Add more info:
The hareware could sustain my application write, I ran application for 1 hours many times, application only crushes occasionally.

This is my class to write file:

```
class BufferedFileStorageManager : IFileStorageManager
{
    private BinaryWriter writer;
    private ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> buffer;
    private bool isWriting;
    private bool isClosed;

    public void Open(string filePath)
    {
        buffer = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();
        writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
        isWriting = false;
        isClosed = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the specified data syncronizly. Method will return after writing finished.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">The data.</param>
    public void Write(byte[] data)
    {
        writer.Write(data);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write the data asyncronizly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">The data.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task WriteAsync(byte[] data)
    {
        if (isClosed)
        {
            var closedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LogManager.Warn("File is closed, skip writing data."));
            await closedTask;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer.Enqueue(data);
            var writeTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(WriteInQueue);
            await writeTask;
        }
    }

    private void WriteInQueue()
    {
        if (isWriting)
            return;

        isWriting = true;

        byte[] data;
        while (buffer.TryDequeue(out data))
        {
            writer.Write(data);
        }

        isWriting = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Close file. Method will return until all pending data is written to file
    /// </summary>
    public void Close()
    {
        WriteInQueue();

        while (isWriting)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        writer.Close();
    }

    public async Task CloseAsync()
    {
        isClosed = true;

        var closeTask = new Task(Close);
        closeTask.Start();
        await closeTask;

        writer.Dispose();
        writer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: First question: can the hardware sustain that level of writes, even under an ideal load test? (Use a storage benchmark tool.) Next question: what makes the writing speed become "very slow"? Other disk activity (anti-virus and backup tools can really slow down disk access)? Some unexplained slowdown in the C# application (not tied to the system IO)? (Use perfmon for a basic resource usage plot.)

Comment: Without knowing exactly how you're reading and writing, my first suggestion is to make sure you're buffering your writes, one large write will typically be faster (less overhead) than many small ones.

Comment: Have you checked the Number of threads open. It is possible that you are running low on thread. It seems unlikely but it is worth checking. Also, Re @Matthew comment. While ... Deque ... {  writer.Write(data); }. could be buffered to a local byte string then written in one chunk.

Comment: @user2246674 : Yes, the hardware sustain the write level, application runs on a very clean machine which do not run other applications. My application only crushes occasionally. Sometimes the application IO is slow down for a while and memory increases a lot, then crushes. I'm not sure how to check it to know if it is code problem or hardware IO problem?

Comment: @Matthew : Thanks Matthew. I added my writing code.

Comment: using booleans for threadsafe locking in this way gives rise to race conditions. It is not fully threadsafe due to compiler optimizations and such. Google on the C# volatile keyword to see what niceties are out there. Switch to using Lock(object){code} or other types of locking